# Change the position of backgroundImage when clicked on searchBar

Tags: ios, background-image, uisearchbar

I have a background image in my search bar:

```
 self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles=nil;
     self.searchBar.showsScopeBar=NO;

     [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-icon-1"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [self.searchBar.layer setBorderWidth:1];
     [self.searchBar.layer setBorderColor:RGB(200,200,200).CGColor];
     self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius=12;
     [self.searchBar sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(216, 56)];
     [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
     [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
     [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:opensans2];
```

By default, when I clicked on my search bar, my background image is moved to the left.

How can I replace it on the center ? ( -> How can i access to the variable `background offset horizontal`, which is present in the storyboard, programmatically?)

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code please.